# What is the correct method of wiping the body after reading the last 3 surahs?

Tags: practical-islam, hadith-interpretation

> Aishah [R.A] reported that the Messenger of Allah [S.A.W] used to recite "Qul huwallahu ahad", "Qul a'oothu birrabilfalaq" and "Qul a'oothu birrabinnaas" every night when he went to sleep, then wiped his face and whatever he was able from his body, beginning with his head and face, and what faces him from his body, three times".
>   [al-Bukhaari #5017](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/66/39)

How exactly should I wipe my face and body? Should I recite the 3 surahs first then spit lightly on my hand and then wipe and then repeat again 2 times? Or should I spit lightly after reading each surah till the third one then wipe my face and my body then repeat? Or some other method?

Also, how exactly should I be blowing on my hands? Please clarify.

Comment: I think none ever thought about questioning this, most hadith commentaries I've seen so far consider it as a given or clear statement as they don't give any interpretation on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need to spit. You may blow on your hands, or just wipe them. Even the ahadith that mention for this type of action (e.g. when awakening from a bad dream) spitting are generally interpreted as a symbolic spitting.